# Windows service usb eject?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I am trying to adapt the following project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32026/Capturing-Device-Events-in-a-C-Windows-Service to detect an usb disk and eject it or stop it from being installed based on an Identification string.
Firstly, the project doesn't run correctly when reaching this portion of code:
 if (hdr.dbcc_devicetype == Win32.DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
                        {

```
                        Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE deviceInterface;
                        deviceInterface = (Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)
                            Marshal.PtrToStructure(eventData, typeof(Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE));

                        string name = new string(deviceInterface.dbcc_name);

                        name = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf('\0')) + "\\";
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                        Win32.GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint(name, stringBuilder, 100);

                        uint stringReturnLength = 0;
                        string driveLetter = "";

                        Win32.GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW(stringBuilder.ToString(), driveLetter, (uint) driveLetter.Length, ref stringReturnLength);



                        if (stringReturnLength == 0)
                        {
                            // TODO handle error
                        }

                        driveLetter = new string(new char[stringReturnLength]);

                        if (!Win32.GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW(stringBuilder.ToString(), driveLetter, stringReturnLength, ref stringReturnLength))
                        {
                            //// TODO handle error
                        }
                        RegisterForHandle(driveLetter[0]);
```

....}
it never gets the drive letter, the driveLetter string is always blank.
The stringBuilder = ôu<¬ë6 and the name variable becomes = \?\USBSTOR#Disk&Ven_&Prod_USB_DISK_2.0&Rev_PMAP#07A512076EB115FA&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}\

What's wrong with it? Or any ideas about what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed existing logic with this new one... This is tested and working for me..

```
writeLog("Device valid");

try
{
    Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE deviceInterface;
    deviceInterface = (Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE)
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(eventData, typeof(Win32.DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE));


    foreach (ManagementObject drive in
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                "select DeviceID, Model from Win32_DiskDrive where InterfaceType='USB'").Get())
    {
        // associate physical disks with partitions
        ManagementObject partition = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format(
            "associators of {{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='{0}'}} where AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition",
            drive["DeviceID"])).First();

        if (partition != null)
        {
            // associate partitions with logical disks (drive letter volumes)
            ManagementObject logical = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format(
                "associators of {{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='{0}'}} where AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition",
                partition["DeviceID"])).First();

            if (logical != null)
            {
                // finally find the logical disk entry to determine the volume name
                ManagementObject volume = new ManagementObjectSearcher(String.Format(
                    "select FreeSpace, Size, VolumeName from Win32_LogicalDisk where Name='{0}'",
                    logical["Name"])).First();

                string capacity = bytesToUnit((ulong)volume["Size"]);
                string freeSpace = bytesToUnit((ulong)volume["FreeSpace"]);

                writeLog("Drive Letter    "     + logical["Name"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                         "Drive Name    "       + volume["VolumeName"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                         "Drive Capacity    "   + capacity + Environment.NewLine +
                         "Drive Free Space    " + freeSpace);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    writeLog("Exception: " + exp.ToString());
}

private string bytesToUnit(ulong bytes)
{
    string[] Suffix = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
    int i = 0;
    double dblSByte = bytes;

    if (bytes > 1024)
    {
        for (i = 0; (bytes / 1024) > 0; i++, bytes /= 1024)
        {
            dblSByte = bytes / 1024.0;
        }
    }
    return String.Format("{0:0.##}{1}", dblSByte, Suffix[i]);
}

public void writeLog(string log)
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry(log);
}
```

**GetResult.cs**

```
public static class GetResult
    {
        public static ManagementObject First(this ManagementObjectSearcher searcher)
        {
            ManagementObject result = null;
            foreach (ManagementObject item in searcher.Get())
            {
                result = item;
                break;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

It will give you all the details that you probably needs.

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

To enumerate the drives use:

```
IEnumerable<DriveInfo> allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(c => c.DriveType == DriveType.Removable);
```

but i don´t know how to remove it